# Deleting Footnotes Temporarily For Better Readability

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

In a document I use `\autocite` and `\footnote`(and biblatex what might not be an important information). I redefined `\footnote` (`\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{}`) in order to produce a document with no personal remarks. Unfortunately, the `\autocite`command seems to be affected and no footnotes are shown at all. How to avoid this effect?

Note: I am aware that I could switch to the inline mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Paul Stanley's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5404/paul-stanley) solution also works, but it *is* possible to have your `biblatex` cake and eat it too, you simply have to tell `biblatex` to use the original definition of footnote in its autocite commands. Luckily as Audrey notes in the comments, this can be done with the `\AtEveryCite` hook that `biblatex` provides. This code is executed at the beginning of each citation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Chomsky1981,
    Address = {Dordrecht},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Booktitle = {Lectures on Government and Binding},
    Publisher = {Foris Publications},
    Title = {Lectures on Government and Binding},
    Year = {1981}}

@book{Chomsky1986,
    Address = {Cambridge, MA},
    Author = {Chomsky, Noam},
    Booktitle = {Barriers},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Barriers},
    Year = {1986}}

@book{Chomsky1982,
    Address = {Cambridge, MA},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Booktitle = {Some Concepts and Consequences of the Theory of Government and Binding},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Some Concepts and Consequences of the Theory of Government and Binding},
    Year = {1982}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\let\origfootnote\footnote % save the original definition of footnote
% Tell biblatex to use the original definition
\AtEveryCite{\let\footnote\origfootnote} 
% make regular footnotes empty
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
In these books \autocite{Chomsky1981, Chomsky1982} Chomsky did lots of syntax.\footnote{This is a footnote.} \kant[1] 
In this book\autocite{Chomsky1986} he revised a bunch of things and made them better.\footnote{This is another footnote.} \kant[2]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

(This is a much simpler version of the answer which previously redefined some of the low-level `biblatex` macros.)

[image: output of code]

Comment: A follow-up question, out of curiosity: how did you find which `biblatex` commands to redefine? `\show\autocite` led me nowhere...

Comment: I think I looked through the code for `footnote`.  `\autocite` itself wouldn't have been much help, since its definition is style dependent.

Comment: I don't understand how looking up the code for footnote would have led you to `\blx@mkbibfootnote` and `\blx@theendnote`. Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: Here's the complete track of what I did (I think).
1. `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}`
2. `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\smartcites}[\iffootnote\mkbibparens\mkbibfootnote]{\smartcite}{\multicitedelim}`
(both in `biblatex.def` )
3. `\newrobustcmd{\mkbibfootnote}{\blx@mkbibfootnote{}}` is defined in `biblatex2.sty` which led to the main redefinition.  `\blx@mkbibfootnote` used `\csuse{footnote#1}` which takes a control sequence name and creates a control sequence out of it. Additionally:
4. `\def\blx@theendnote{\blx@err@endnote\footnote}` needs to be redefined too.

Comment: I think `\AtEveryCite{\let\footnote\origfootnote}` would also do fine.

Comment: @Audrey Thanks! That makes the answer much simpler.  There's so much stuff built into `biblatex` it's always hard to know what the best way to do things is.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have footnotes, `biblatex` can't put citations into footnotes! All `\autocite` is doing is putting citations into a `\footnote`, and your redefinition is working to remove them all.

If you want to create a "personal" footnote command which can be switched off, could you not define your own command to use in place of `\footnote`:

```
\newcommand{\myfootnote}[1]{\footnote{#1}}
```

Then when you want to turn footnotes off, you can redefine this command, while leaving the underlying `\footnote` command untouched. (The alternative, as you point out, is to switch to inline citations when you turn your footnotes off.)